# PPTP client behind a NAT: how do I forward port

Tags: virtual-machine, vpn, pptp

The setup is as follows:

1. PPTP Windows server over Internets (SERVER)
2. Windows Host Machine (HOST)
3. Linux VM running on Machine 2 (VM)

VM runs on HOST with its network adapter attached to NAT.

HOST can access SERVER over VPN with the given set of credentials without a problem. VM running on HOST cannot. Tcpdump shows what to me looks like lack of GRE responses:

```
17:17:17.024882 IP $VM_IP.46712 > $SERVER_IP.pptp: Flags [S], seq 223797697, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2041885 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
17:17:17.265478 IP $SERVER_IP.pptp > $VM_IP.46712: Flags [S.], seq 284096001, ack 223797698, win 65535, options [mss 1460], length 0
17:17:17.265531 IP $VM_IP.46712 > $SERVER_IP.pptp: Flags [.], ack 1, win 29200, length 0
17:17:17.266374 IP $VM_IP.46712 > $SERVER_IP.pptp: Flags [P.], seq 1:157, ack 1, win 29200, length 156: pptp CTRL_MSGTYPE=SCCRQ PROTO_VER(1.0) FRAME_CAP(AS) BEARER_CAP(DA) MAX_CHAN(65535) FIRM_REV(1) HOSTNAME(local) VENDOR(cananian)
17:17:17.266576 IP $SERVER_IP.pptp > $VM_IP.46712: Flags [.], ack 157, win 65535, length 0
17:17:17.512333 IP $SERVER_IP.pptp > $VM_IP.46712: Flags [P.], seq 1:157, ack 157, win 65535, length 156: pptp CTRL_MSGTYPE=SCCRP PROTO_VER(1.0) RESULT_CODE(1) ERR_CODE(0) FRAME_CAP() BEARER_CAP() MAX_CHAN(1) FIRM_REV(1) HOSTNAME(local) VENDOR(linux)
17:17:17.512370 IP $VM_IP.46712 > $SERVER_IP.pptp: Flags [.], ack 157, win 30016, length 0
17:17:18.267029 IP $VM_IP.46712 > $SERVER_IP.pptp: Flags [P.], seq 157:325, ack 157, win 30016, length 168: pptp CTRL_MSGTYPE=OCRQ CALL_ID(0) CALL_SER_NUM(0) MIN_BPS(2400) MAX_BPS(10000000) BEARER_TYPE(Any) FRAME_TYPE(E) RECV_WIN(3) PROC_DELAY(0) PHONE_NO_LEN(0) PHONE_NO() SUB_ADDR()
17:17:18.267276 IP $SERVER_IP.pptp > $VM_IP.46712: Flags [.], ack 325, win 65535, length 0
17:17:18.516316 IP $SERVER_IP.pptp > $VM_IP.46712: Flags [P.], seq 157:189, ack 325, win 65535, length 32: pptp CTRL_MSGTYPE=OCRP CALL_ID(9) PEER_CALL_ID(0) RESULT_CODE(1) ERR_CODE(0) CAUSE_CODE(0) CONN_SPEED(10000000) RECV_WIN(3) PROC_DELAY(0) PHY_CHAN_ID(0)
17:17:18.516353 IP $VM_IP.46712 > $SERVER_IP.pptp: Flags [.], ack 189, win 30016, length 0
17:17:18.516617 IP $VM_IP > $SERVER_IP: GREv1, call 9, seq 1, length 36: LCP, Conf-Request (0x01), id 1, length 22
17:17:21.013567 IP $VM_IP > $SERVER_IP: GREv1, call 9, seq 2, length 36: LCP, Conf-Request (0x01), id 1, length 22
17:17:24.018211 IP $VM_IP > $SERVER_IP: GREv1, call 9, seq 3, length 36: LCP, Conf-Request (0x01), id 1, length 22
17:17:27.021510 IP $VM_IP > $SERVER_IP: GREv1, call 9, seq 4, length 36: LCP, Conf-Request (0x01), id 1, length 22
17:17:30.024770 IP $VM_IP > $SERVER_IP: GREv1, call 9, seq 5, length 36: LCP, Conf-Request (0x01), id 1, length 22
17:17:33.027047 IP $VM_IP > $SERVER_IP: GREv1, call 9, seq 6, length 36: LCP, Conf-Request (0x01), id 1, length 22
17:17:36.030701 IP $VM_IP > $SERVER_IP: GREv1, call 9, seq 7, length 36: LCP, Conf-Request (0x01), id 1, length 22
17:17:39.034014 IP $VM_IP > $SERVER_IP: GREv1, call 9, seq 8, length 36: LCP, Conf-Request (0x01), id 1, length 22
17:17:42.037526 IP $VM_IP > $SERVER_IP: GREv1, call 9, seq 9, length 36: LCP, Conf-Request (0x01), id 1, length 22
17:17:45.040779 IP $VM_IP > $SERVER_IP: GREv1, call 9, seq 10, length 36: LCP, Conf-Request (0x01), id 1, length 22
17:17:48.048560 IP $VM_IP.46712 > $SERVER_IP.pptp: Flags [P.], seq 325:341, ack 189, win 30016, length 16: pptp CTRL_MSGTYPE=CCRQ CALL_ID(0)
17:17:48.048649 IP $VM_IP.46712 > $SERVER_IP.pptp: Flags [F.], seq 341, ack 189, win 30016, length 0
17:17:48.048685 IP $SERVER_IP.pptp > $VM_IP.46712: Flags [.], ack 341, win 65535, length 0
17:17:48.049126 IP $SERVER_IP.pptp > $VM_IP.46712: Flags [.], ack 342, win 65535, length 0
17:17:54.359765 IP $SERVER_IP.pptp > $VM_IP.46712: Flags [F.], seq 189, ack 342, win 65535, length 0
17:17:54.359810 IP $VM_IP.46712 > $SERVER_IP.pptp: Flags [.], ack 190, win 30016, length 0
```

**Question:** should I forward additional ports through the hypervisor on HOST to VM, or am I missing something altogether?

Comment: PPTP is insecure and has been deprecated for years. Please switch to a proper VPN portocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Assuming you use Linux] You probably need to add support for "nf_conntrack_pptp" - I posit that NAT is not associating the GRE packets with PPTP, and is thus not forwarding them.    Depending on your variant, modprobe nf_conntrack_pptp may work temporarily, playing with /etc/modprobe.d/* or adding it to /etc/modules may be a perm fix if that is the cause of the problem.

Comment: I made edits to the question to make it more clear on OSes used. nf_conntrack_pptp is loaded in guest: # grep pptp /proc/modules
nf_conntrack_pptp 19257 0 - Live 0xffffffffa0261000

Comment: nf_conntrack_pptp needs to be done on the host (to navigate it through NAT), not the guest.